# Algorithm to calculare from 3-digit number any number in range 000000-999999

Tags: algorithm

I need algorithm which calculare from 3-digit number any number in range 000000-999999.

There must be able to calculare number reverse from range in 000000-999999 to 3-digit number.

Algorithm must be universal for all combinations in specified ranges.

Any ideas?

(It should be formula, where when will be filled single numbers from 3-digit number then output will be corresponding 6-digit number)

Comment: Can you provide an example for a particular number? That would make your question more clear. Also, you say 9-digit number but 999999 only has 6 digits

Comment: Not clear.  Provide sample input and the desired result.

Comment: This is impossible.  There are only 1000 3-digit numbers, so 999000 of those target numbers cannot be generated.

Comment: Sure, for example I have number "415944", I need 3-digit combination from which will be calculated with asked algorithm number "415944", here it is from opposite, than is problem described in question, because I think that it is more comprehensible

Comment: well, algorithm can be for example like 3-digit number "XYZ" where algorithm will work like (X) x (Y x Y) x (Z x Z x Z) but it of course not work, but i think that there is really many options, there can be applied any operations between numbers

Comment: Sit down and think hard about what j_random_hacker said. Sit, think, and process the information. What you want to do is **impossible**. If it was possible to represent a 6 digit number with 3 digits, then we wouldn't have 6 digit numbers. You have 1000 unique combinations to play with, how could you possibly represent 1000000 numbers with 1000 combinations? Think about it.

Comment: sure, thanks guys, thats right, that there is only 1k combinations, so output will be with 1 same algorithm always only 1k numbers

Answer (score 1):

The direction 6-digit number to 3-digit number can be done by collapsing multiple 6-digit values together into a 3-digit range.  A simple technique for this is to take the modulo of the original number with 1000, resulting in something from 0 to 999

```
int threeDigit = sixDigit % 1000;
```

Transforming the three digit number back into the original six digit number is theoretically impossible, no matter what algorithm you use to map the 6-digit number onto 3-digit numbers, because information was lost in the original conversion process.